# Copying from another website

Tags: discussion, documentation

If someone proposed some changes ([Proposed Changes: HTML Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/23338?draftId=21431)) and it was an exact copy of another website ([w3schools: HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)), should the changes be accepted or rejected?

Comment: The purpose of the site is to document what is not already well documented. Also plagiarism is illegal. So I would say, no, the change should not be accepted. The person should write their own documentation and include links to the W3Schools page.

Comment: @TotZam W3Schools doesn't inspire trustiness either way...

Comment: You have to give attribution. If you did and the original license is compatible and you can make it better than at the original location, go for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a reason to reject an example called "copied content", to reject content that was copied from another website without proper attribution.

So you should reject the changes if there is no proper attribution to the source.

Comment: Even with attribution it is not fair use.

Comment: I agree with you, there has been a lot of people trying to get easy reputation from the documentation kick-off. I've been in the private beta, and yesterday i had a hard time protecting good content from people who just wanted the easy reputation by making un-productive edits.

Comment: "without proper attribution" *this* needs to be documented or linked next to the textarea.